# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los valores de otra tabla. Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo mis migraciones que van mas o menos asi

**CONTRATOS**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contracts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('java', 191)->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('method_payment');
        $table->integer('kpi_dni')->nullable();
        $table->integer('kpi_ruc')->nullable();
        $table->integer('kpi_pos')->nullable();
        $table->integer('kpi_out')->nullable();
```

**CLIENTES**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedInteger('document_user')->default(1);
        $table->string('document')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('document_user')
            ->references('id')->on('document_users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**CONTRATO CLIENTE**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contract_client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('contract_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

tengo mis modelos de la siguiente manera

**CONTRATOS**

```
    class Contract extends Model
{


    public function clients()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Client')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**CLIENTES**

```
    class Client extends Model{
    public function contracts()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Contract')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**CONTRATO CLIENTE**

```
    class ContractClient extends Model{
    protected $table='contract_client';

    protected $fillable = [
        'contract_id', 'client_id'
    ];
    public function contract(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contract', 'id', 'contract_id');
    }
    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client', 'id', 'client_id');
    }


}
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar al cliente del contrato, pensé en algunas soluciones sin alcanzar la solución.

```
@foreach ($contracts as $contract)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$contract->clients()->get()}}</td>
```

pero me da un error en el cual dice que mi tabla no la encuentra la cual es **client_contract**, pero por obvias razones, porque yo la tengo como **contract_client**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi DB

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: duda, por que tienes el nombre de la tabla distinto a como esta en la base de datos?

Comment: eso es lo raro, que no lo tengo asi, es mas no tengo esa bd en ningun lado, agregare una imagen de mi db

Comment: ¿qué aparece en el .env al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para especificar el modelo que une esta relación Varios a Varios debes usar el método:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Client')
        ->using('App\ContractClient')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

De esta manera especificas la tabla que rompe la relación.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré, te confirmo.

Comment: Gracias, lo hice en otro archivo y funcionó.